# Make flask return NON-json response custom message with error code

Tags: json, flask, request, response, http-status-code-403

How do I return a custom response message with error 403 that is NOT json.
I have tried using this:

```
    def bad_request(message):
        response = jsonify({'message': message})
        response.status_code = 403
        return response

   @app.route("/logs")
    def logs():
        if request.remote_addr == "127.0.0.1":
            return f"Heres your logs!"
        else:
            return bad_request('WAF: Access Denied for this Host.')
```

This returns json, which I dont want. Also, I dont like using abort as it includes HTML. I only want the response to be 403, and print the flat text ONLY.

I tried changing `response = jsonify({'message': message})` to `response = message` but I get an internal server error with "AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'status_code'"

How can I accomplish this?

**EDIT:**
Finally was able to get this to work with

```
 return render_template('error.html'), 403
```

And just putting the flat text in error.html.
It there any other way to accomplish this without having to create a template html file?

Answer (score 0):

The value you return from a Flask view should always be a `Response`:

```
from flask import Response

def logs():
   ...
   return Response("WAF: Access Denied for this Host.", status=403)
```